# Cisco 3850 Input Current

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst

I am trying to determine what the labeling on the back of one of our Cisco 3850 switches means.

We are seeing `12-6A` on the back of the power supply, and I've pinned it down to be the Input Current based on Cisco documentation.

I cannot determine what the `12` stands for.  Does anyone have more insight on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a universal PSU - 12 A is for ca. 120 V and 6 A for 230 V AC.

Note that this isn't what's pulled all the time, it's the peak current on startup, peak load etc.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense now.  I'll vote this as the answer when it allows me!